# Git config alias issue

Tags: git, bash, shell, merge, git-config

I'm trying to create an alias for my "merge to staging" workflow.

Let's say I've finished a task in branch "dev/layout_fix" and want to deploy it to staging after commiting.

This is my way:

1. `git checkout staging`
2. `git merge dev/layout_fix --no-ff`
3. `git push`
4. `git checkout dev/layout_fix`

Now I've tried this approach:

`[alias]
branch-name = "!git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD"
stagify = "!git checkout staging && git merge $(git branch-name) --no-ff && git push && git checkout $(git branch-name)"`

but the alias branch-name is "staging" because of the checkout.

Is it possible to write the current branch name in a variable before staging is checked out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a possibility to write the current branch name in a variable before staging is checked out?

Sure.  Since you're prefixing your git aliases with `!`, they're just shells scripts.  So you can stick the output of git commands into variables the same way you would for any shell script, e.g., something like this:

```
[alias]
branch-name = "rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD"                             
mybranch = "!branch=$(git branch-name); echo my branch is: $branch"
```

With that defined, I can run this:

```
git mybranch
```

And get:

```
my branch is: master
```

That ought to be enough to get you going.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current branch name using `git describe --exact-match --all`.

Instead of an alias, you can write a script and deploy it to `/usr/libexec/git`. You just have to place it there and call it `git-stagify`. I'm writing this from memory, but I believe that's the default path. You can find it by searching for where `git-pull` is located (with the dash), using `locate` or whatever is available in your distribution. This will give you the full benefits of the bash scripting environment, that may be missing when simply using aliases.

Answer (score 0):

The full alias command looks like:

`stagify = "!branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) && git checkout staging && git merge $branch --no-ff && git push && git checkout $branch"`

Thanks to @larsks for the right approach.

Comment: One note: `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` will print `HEAD` when you're in detached-HEAD mode.  This is often the right answer, but not useful for your final goal (which involves changing `HEAD` temporarily).  You might want to use `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD` instead, which will make the whole sequence fail (probably what you want—the other option is to merge by commit ID, which is a valid thing to do but perhaps not what you would like).